# Send more than one parameter in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

I am trying to send multiple data using ajaxFileUpload.But only i am able to send the file from the ajax call.Can any one help me to send multiple data with the ajax call.Here is my code

```
function sendToConsultant(){

    var fname = $('#<portlet:namespace />fname').val();
    var lname = $('#<portlet:namespace />lname').val();
    var email = $('#<portlet:namespace />email').val();
    var phone = $('#<portlet:namespace />phone').val();
    var jobtitle = $('#<portlet:namespace />jobtitle').val();
    var comments = $('#<portlet:namespace />comments').val();
     var url = "<%=candidateInterestURL%>";

    var fname = $('#<portlet:namespace />fname').val();
    var lname = $('#<portlet:namespace />lname').val();
    var email = $('#<portlet:namespace />email').val();
    var phone = $('#<portlet:namespace />phone').val();
    var jobtitle = $('#<portlet:namespace />jobtitle').val();
    var comments = $('#<portlet:namespace />comments').val();
    var type = "candidateInterestInJob";



   $.ajaxFileUpload({

        url:'<%=candidateInterestURL%>',
        secureuri : false,
        fileElementId : 'fileName',
        dataType : 'json',
        data:{'fname':fname,'lname':lname},
        success : function(data, status) {

            alert('hiii');
         },
         error:function (data, status, e){
             alert("There might be some issue with this file.");
         }
    });
```

This is the code i am using,But it is not working .Someone please help me Thnanks in advance.Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes for your parameter names like this,

```
data:{"fname":fname,"lname":lname},
```

Comment: A.Wolf can you help??

Comment: @lucifer not really, i'm afraid. You should provide minimalistic sample in question to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0):

With `ajaxFileUpload` sending additional data is not possible beacuse the option `data` that you use in your code is not available in the js library. Try using different jQuery plugin like [jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) where you can send additional data through `formData` option.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order. Firt name then value:

```
    data:{fname:"fname" , lname:"lname"},
```